# Using environment variable as build number with fastlane

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane

I want my iOS releases to use the `CI_PIPELINE_ID` as build number. To do so i have a script that updates the xcconfig which sets `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION`.

Since i switched using fastlane i tried to get rid of this custom script and use fastlane functions. [increment_build_number](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/increment_build_number/) seems to do exactly what i am looking for but i am unable to access the `ENV` variable. According to [the fastlane ENV docu](https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/other/#environment-variables) env variables should be accessible.

How can i access the environment variables to make this work?

```swift
desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
lane :beta do
  increment_build_number(
    build_number: ENV("CI_PIPELINE_ID") # set a specific number
  )
  ...
...
```

Comment: The examples in the documentation of dotenv use square brackets: `ENV["CI_PIPELINE_ID"]`.